# cloning full site to local include images CSS file

Tags: clone, wget

I want to clone a site and keep file structure as site original, like have CSS folder, images folder etc. all things are the same on the web, is there some tools can achieve this, I have tried:

```
wget -m http://www.xxx.com
```

but it's seem didn't contain CSS, JS file because they in a different sub-domain like tech.xxx.com

Comment: This isn't really programming related.  Should get moved to superuser.com.

Comment: Checkout out http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget Works great for offline browsing or backup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used DownloadThemAll! FireFox add-on and it works pretty well.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/

[image: DownloadThemAll! Screen Shot]